# set value to select2 dropdown which retrieved from database in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
//following values i retrived from database and i want to display into select2 dropdown
var selectedValue1 = '43,48,47,57'; 

$('#ddlCity1').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 0, //for listing all records > set 0
        maximumInputLength: 20, //only allow terms up to 20 characters long
        multiple: true,
        placeholder: "Select",
        allowClear: true,
        tags: false, //prevent free text entry
        width: "100%",
        ajax: {
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCityList", "DemoMVC")',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    searchTerm: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                var newData = [];
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    newData.push({
                        //id part present in data
                        id: item.Id,
                        //string to be displayed
                        text: item.City
                    });
                });
                return { results: newData };
            },
            cache: true
        },            
    });

    $(".city1").on("select2:select", function (e) {
        currentSelectedVal = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        console.log(currentSelectedVal) // get selected values
    });

    $('.city1').on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
        currentSelectedVal = $(e.currentTarget).val();
        console.log(currentSelectedVal) // get selected values
        
    });
```

});

```
//Dropdown with select2 control
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>City</label>
            <select id="ddlCity1" class="city1" style="width:500px"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, rather than just a block of code could you add a description of the problem you are having and what you have tried. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i assume that this action "GetCityList" returned json

```js
$('#ddlCity1').select2({ minimumInputLength: 0, //for listing all records > set 0 
            maximumInputLength: 20, //only allow terms up to 20 characters long 
            multiple: true, 
            placeholder: "Select", 
            allowClear: true, 
            tags: false, //prevent free text entry 
            width: "100%"
            });
                    function ("/DemoMVC/GetCityList", {}, "json", success, falier) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: paramters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: returnFormat,
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
                let htmlData = "<option value='' selected disabled hidden>Select City...</option>";
                            
                            for (let i = 0; i < Object.values(data)[1].length; i++) {
                                htmlData = htmlData + Template(Object.values(data)[1][i]);
                                }
                            $("#ddlCity1").html(htmlData);
            },
            
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + ': ' + xhr.responseText + ': ';
                console.log('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            },
            type: 'GET',

        });
    }
    function Template(item) {
                        let itemHtml = "<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.city + "</option>";
                        return itemHtml;
                    }
```